# Error 403: Server Failed to Authenticate the request

Tags: bash, shell, azure-devops, wget, azure-artifacts

I am trying to download a file from from Azure Artifact package using their Rest API.

```
wget --header="Authorization: Basic $PAT" "$URL" -O $filename
```

I am getting error message

```
ERROR:403 Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can download the file Azure Artifact package using the Rest API in PowerShell.

The following is a sample to download a NuGet package with [NuGet - Download Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifactspackagetypes/nuget/download-package?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1). If you want to download other types, you can change the `apiUrl` with the one you need.

```
$pat=""
$filename=""

$apiUrl ="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/packaging/feeds/{feedId}/nuget/packages/{packageName}/versions/{packageVersion}/content?api-version=6.1-preview.1"

# Use Invoke-RestMethod to download the package
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers @{ Authorization = "Basic " + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$pat")) } -OutFile $filename

# Check if the download was successful
if ($?) {
    Write-Host "Package downloaded successfully: $filename"
} else {
    Write-Host "Error downloading package."
}
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for answering, Mind if i ask what type of pat are you using or I should use! Azure Devops PAT or Azure AD token?

Comment: Hi, I am using [the Azure DevOps PAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows#create-a-pat)

Comment: `Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was
detected from the client` When I try these same commands it prompts this!

Comment: Its resolved now. Their was problem with how i framed my uri. Thank you.